# Is there an equivalent to string / list slicing in C++, like in Python?

Tags: python, c++

I'm learning C++ whilst being fairly good at Python. Is there a slicing equivalent in C++ like in Python?

```
# Python

person = "Jimmy"
print(person[1:-1]) # imm
```

```
// c++

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    string name = "Jimmy";
    cout << name[1:-1] << endl; // imm
}
```

Thanks

Here is the error:

`

```
random.cpp: In function 'int main()':
random.cpp:8:19: error: expected ']' before ':' token
     cout << name[1:-1] << endl; // imm
                   ^
random.cpp:8:19: error: expected ';' before ':' token
```

`

Comment: No C++ doens't have any kind of slicing built-in. To solve your problem, specifically for `std::string`, use [`substr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Comment: `#include <ranges>` has something similar. But it's generalized for any container, so you might not be able to easily print the resulting substring like that.